# HTTPInterceptor in angular 7 is behaving strangely

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-http-interceptors

I have a very simple interceptor that intercepts errors and prints the output on the console:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.status == 401) {
                console.log("Error 401", error);
            }
            else if (error.status == 404) {
                console.log("Error 404", error);
            }
            else if (error.status == 0) {
                console.log("Unknown error", error);
                sendRequestAgain();
            } else{
               // do nothing
            }
            return throwError(error)
        })
    );
}
```

The problem is that when I get `error.status==0`, it works perfectly the first time and the request is sent again (with `sendRequestAgain()`), but when the request fails the second time, the error is intercepted correctly but the control doesn't go in `else if (error.status == 0) {` block. Instead, it goes down to the else block. I've printed out the error and it is exactly same both the times. Even the breakpoint on `else if (error.status == 0) {` is not hit the second time which is totally strange.

Any ideas?

Comment: the `catchError` operator is supposed to return an Observable. Try returning something, see if your error persists.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Let me try that.

Comment: Updated the question. I am returning an observable now

Comment: Still the same behavior

Comment: `console.log(error.status)` would still show 0?

Comment: @mbojko Yes. It still shows zero on the second time the error occurs if logged in the last else or at the end before returning from catchError.

Comment: Let me be sure that i understand the question. You want to handle all the error and if the error code is 0 to retry the http call?

Comment: Yes exactly. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I did try rxjs retry as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to merge map and check if the error is the error you want to retry, in this case i use 404, and if it is, you set the rxjs timer before the next request is processed and finally after use the operator take to set how many time to retry the connection. If the error is not the error that you want to retry than simply retrow the error again and handled it like nothing happen before.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable, throwError, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, mergeMap, retryWhen, take} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class EnsureHttpsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors
          .pipe(
            mergeMap(error => error.status === 404 ? timer(5000) : throwError(error)),
            take(2)
          );
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {

        switch (error.status) {
          case 401:
            console.log('Error 401', error);
            break;
          case 404:
            console.log('404', error);
            break;
          default:
            return throwError(error);
        }

      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code only retries twice. Is it possible to retry indefinitely? And more importantly, is it a good idea to keep on retrying until the backend is up. My services are running in docker swarm and it is pretty much guaranteed that the service will be up sooner or later if it crashed.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed it is *not* a good idea to keep on retrying indefinitely until the backend is up...unless you back off with increasing delays. You may doom your struggling back end.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Ok. Increasing delays seems like a better approach then. So how do I modify the above code to keep on trying indefinitely with increasing delay? I can conjure up something to keep on increasing the delays but retryWhen is only retrying twice. How can I go about that?

Comment: Tried removing take(2), but it is still retrying twice :\

Comment: removing take, will end up retrying until it get an error code different from the 404 in my case, it will continue to make request based on the timer setting, in my case  if i remove take it will request every 5 second indefinetrly, IMHO you should set a max retry time with take.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. It is working now. I'll go with having a max retry count. Thanks.

Comment: @SaqibAhmed [exponential backoff](https://blog.angularindepth.com/power-of-rxjs-when-using-exponential-backoff-a4b8bde276b0) example but you can also maintain via http interceptor statistics on api calls and act appropriately